# Image can't be clicked after creating jquery-ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a menu made with jquery-ui tabs. Under this menu I have a little image inside an hyperlink tag that can be clicked (as you can see on the picture), but once the tabs are created, I can't click on this image on some browsers. It only works on IE, if I try with Firefox or Chrome it doesn't receive the click.

[image]

Any tips? And why does it only works on IE?

Comment: Probably because IE (depending on version) does not respect zIndex correctly, but most other browsers do; i.e. there is probably another element sitting on top of it, not allowing the click to occur.

Answer (score 0):

This the tab menu made out of html5? Attached this to the head of your document:

`<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>`

Explanation here -->https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

IE tends to have problems in older versions...